# Tradução de "edit the above snippet" e "expand snippet"

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução

Falta tradução das expressões

"edit the above snippet" e "expand snippet"

[image: screenshot do problema]

Provavelmente seja o caso de traduzir para

"Editar o trecho de código acima" e "expandir trecho de código"

ou coisa do tipo.

(Editado para acrescentar a observação do @Victor)

Comment: **Expand snippet**

Answer (score 8):

Está traduzido no [Transifex do SOpt](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-pt/) aguardando revisão e inserção no sistema.

Quem quiser pode participar lá.

Comment: Como notado pelo Victor, o "Expand snippet" logo ao lado também está faltando :)

Comment: Está feito também.